# scalaquery problem no implicit session

Tags: scala, scalaquery

this is a scalaquery query which i want to perform,

```
...
def generateFares(scheduleId:NamedColumn[Int], toCityId:NamedColumn[Int], fromCityId:NamedColumn[Int]):List[(String,Int,String)] = {
      var list:List[(String,Int,String)] = Nil;
      val q = for {
        tf <- ticketingDB.ticketFares if (( tf.scheduleId is scheduleId ) && ( tf.fromCityId is fromCityId ) && ( tf.toCityId is toCityId ))
        tft <- ticketingDB.ticketFareType if tft.id is tf._7
      }{
        list = (tft._2, tf._5, tf._6)::list
      }
      list
    }
...
```

In this join, i'm getting a compilation error:

```
 could not find implicit value for parameter session: org.scalaquery.session.Session
```

in the second call. (tft <- ticketingDB)

i cannot understand this behavior of scalaquery.

ps: i can assure the method is called inside a withSession block.

please help me to debug and create error free join.

Comment: sorry to bother you guys, but i figured the solution myself. i hadn't imported threadLocalSession to the file.

import org.scalaquery.session.Database.threadLocalSession

Comment: if you figure out the answer on your own, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 14):

Sorry, I post the solution as a comment,

I figured the answer myself. you should import threadLocalSession to get the session object.

```
import org.scalaquery.session.Database.threadLocalSession
```

Comment: For slick:   `import scala.slick.session.Database.threadLocalSession`

Comment: Slick 2.0 requires a different import: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/migration.html#dynamically-and-statically-scoped-sessions